# 2 divs on row one and 2 divs on row two

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something like the 3rd page of this website: https://nicolesaidy.com/ I have 4 pictures in 4 divs and I want to put text under every image, I tried absolute styling but that does not look good on every screen resolution. What would be the best way to do this?

```css
 .tutorials {
      margin: 15% auto 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .panda img {
      max-width:100%;
      float:left;
    }
    
    .paper img {
      max-width:100%;
      float:left;
    }
    
    .santa img {
      max-width:100%;
      float:left;
    }
    
    .swan img {
      max-width:100%;
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="tutorials">
      <div class="panda">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Panda">
    </div>
    <div class="paper">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Paper" height="100" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="santa">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Santa" height="100" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="swan">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Swan" height="100" width="100">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Display as inline-block and make their width 50%? (and ditch the floats) Would be my first try, might also want to use media queries to make it one-per-line on thinner screens to avoid them looking nasty at lower resolutions.

Comment: Have you used view page source and also inspected the CSS of the site that you like?

Comment: I did, when I hovered over the elements I saw multiple blocks but I could not make anything out of it

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div class="tutorials">
  <div class="half panda">
     <img src="images/panda.png" alt="Panda" height="100" width="100">
     <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="half paper">
    <img src="images/paper.png" alt="Paper" height="100" width="100">
   <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tutorials">
  <div class="half santa">
    <img src="images/santa.png" alt="Santa" height="100" width="100">
   <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="half swan">
    <img src="images/swan.png" alt="Swan" height="100" width="100">
   <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>



.half{width:50%;float:left;display:inline-block}
.tutorials{margin : 15% auto}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you edit your code so that it is also centered to the middle of the page?

Comment: you can give .tutorials a certain width and auto margin

Answer (score 0):

I used flex

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
  <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 500px;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

example: https://codepen.io/Czeran/pen/XzbdrP

Answer (score 0):

I have used CSS flex ( [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) + [A complete guide to flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ) to meet your requirements. I also have added some comments to the css to explain what a given rule does.

```css
/* your website container */
.container {
  width: 30em; /* width of your website */
  /* added a border to indicate the website space, just for presentation purpose */
  border: 1px solid red; 
}

/* this style determines the appearance of the container that consists all your boxes */
.tutorials {
  display: flex;
  width: 20em;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers this box to your website container */
}


/* this style determines the appearance of each boxes */

.box {
  height: 15em;
  /* ensures that there is some white space in your box */
  padding: 0.6em 0.4em;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* this style determines the appearance of the image in the box */

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}


/* this style determines the appearance of the text below your image */

.box p {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  /* centers the text towards the box */
}

.container .item {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tutorials">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://assets1.tribesports.com/system/challenges/images/000/025/490/original/20120823035328-random-challenge-generator.jpg" alt="Panda" height="100" width="100">
      <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://hackster.imgix.net/uploads/cover_image/file/170541/dice1.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&w=600&h=450&fit=min" alt="Paper" height="100" width="100">
      <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://5found.com/images/2012/04/Random-number-generator.png" alt="Santa" height="100" width="100">
      <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://payload23.cargocollective.com/1/6/200664/2775040/Screen%20Shot%202012-01-20%20at%2013.52.19.png" alt="Swan" height="100" width="100">
      <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Another stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.parent{
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}

.child{
width:50%;
float:left;
margin-bottom:10px;
display:block;

}

.child p {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.child img{
max-width:95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also u can try:

`<figure class="box">
  <img src="some_image.png" alt="Image" height="100" width="100">
  <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
</figure>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp